# Why converting date format is wrong in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
- (NSString *) displayInvitationDate:(NSString *)paramDate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: paramDate];
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM"];
    NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    return convertedString;
}
```

That's calling above function

```
[self displayInvitationDate:@"2016-02-27"];
```

Oddly result is

```
Wed 27 JAN
```

and result should be

```
SAT 27 JAN
```

Please let me know which part got wrong above my coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this line.

`[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZonetimeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];`

and chanfe your pass foemat  `yyyy-mm-dd` to replace `yyyy-MM-dd`, For set as....

`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];`

For more Details Data time Format to [Click Now](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help you